# iOS app mms message image shows up on android as xml

Tags: android, ios, mms

My iOS app sends images between phones and it's working on iOS but Android users seem to receive xml instead of an image. Here's what they see on Android. What would cause this and how can I fix it?

`<mil> <Heab> <diseño> <raíz-diseño /> <region id = "text" top = "70%" left = "0%" height = "30%" width = "100%" fit = "scroll" /> <region id = "image" top = "0%" left = "0%" height = "70%" width = "100%" fit = "meet" /> </ Lay`